# Kelly criterion for normally distributed returns

Tags: risk-management, kelly-criterion, money-management

If the returns of my strategy are distributed like [μ,σ], what is the optimal fraction of capital to invest in each single trade, as a function **μ** and **σ**?  Help!

PS. I know that normally distributed returns are an abstraction. But I'd like to grasp the concept in an ideal world, before exploring the implications of fat tails on the formula...

Comment: Do you assume you close each trade at the beginning of the next investment period ?

Comment: yes, I do 1 trade per period. There are never 2 trades open at the same time.

Comment: Have you perused Thorp’s papers, for instance, http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/cs286r/courses/fall12/papers/Thorpe_KellyCriterion2007.pdf , for one derivation? Another can be done via Itô’s lemma, iirc.

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This problem can be expressed as the original [Merton's portfolio problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merton%27s_portfolio_problem).

Consider wealth process defined by SDE

$$
d X _ { t } = \frac { X _ { t } \alpha _ { t } } { S _ { t } } d S _ { t } + \frac { X _ { t } \left( 1 - \alpha _ { t } \right) } { S _ { t } ^ { 0 } } d S _ { t } ^ { 0 }
$$

where $\alpha_t$ is proportion of the investment in the risky asset $S_t$, and $S_t^0$ is the risk-free asset.

Optimality criterion may depend on the risk aversion of the investor, and the problem is to maximize expected utility of the investor for appropriate utility function $U$:

$$
E \left[ U \left( X _ { T } \right) \right] \rightarrow \max
$$

Classical choice of the utility function is CRRA:

$$
u ( x ) = \frac { x ^ { 1 - \gamma } } { 1 - \gamma }
$$

where $\gamma$ is constant and corresponds to the risk-aversion of the investor.

If the asset $S_t$ follows Black-Scholes dynamics (in conformance with your assumption of log-normal returns)

$$
\begin{aligned} d S _ { t } ^ { 0 } & = r S _ { t } ^ { 0 } d t \\ d S _ { t } & = \mu S _ { t } d t + \sigma S _ { t } d W _ { t } \end{aligned}
$$

remarkably there is a closed-form solution which it is to invest a constant proportion of wealth in the risky asset

$$
\alpha_t = \frac { \mu - r } { \gamma \sigma ^ { 2 } }
$$

Notice that the solution can be interpreted as the mean-variance trade-off.

Comment: Note also that for log-utility (the Kelly case) $\gamma=1$

Comment: @nakajuice thanks for the answer! I can't explain this case though. If we suppose γ=1 (kelly case), r=0, μ=0.01€ and σ=0.05€ we get ⍺=4. How can ⍺>1?

Comment: We assume short-selling is allowed. $\alpha=4$ implies that for each 4 shares you hold, you need to short-sell 3 bonds (read: borrow money).

Answer (score 2):

ok I found it and this works for any distribution, not just the normal distribution

$f^*=\frac μ {σ^2 + μ^2} \approx \frac μ {σ^2} \space if μ\llσ$

here the steps: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4nqd5yfk2xcuag5/kelly.pdf

Comment: This answer is close to, but not identical, to the other well-known one. It would be interesting to understand why the difference.

Comment: Why don't they just do $$ E(\prod_i (1 + f r_i)) = \prod_i E(1 + f r_i) = (1 + f  \mu)^t$$ since the $$r_i$$ are IID? I am probably doing something dumb here.

Comment: @mathtick I am trying to figure that out myself too. Can it be that:


$\frac d {df} E\left[\prod_{i=1}^t(1+f\space r_i)\right] \ne
\frac d {df}(1+f\space μ)^t$ 


that is, for some property of the $E[ ... ]$ operator, you must first differentiate and then apply the $E[ ... ]$ operator?

Comment: @elemolotiv I read a lot more after that post ... so basically Kelly is exactly what I wrote above, and then then exp/log and end up maximizing the mean of the $\log(1 + f u)$ in the exponential.  So basically, in the most general sense, "Kelly" just means use a log-utility when balancing risks.

A key thing that they miss, is that the log is only defined *if you survive*. i.e. you don't go bust. So there is a term missing in most of this stuff to do with $P(1 + f r < 0)$ that one should do something with.

Comment: Thanks! @mathtick Your comment helped me realise that maximising [log()] is not a mathematically convenient way to maximise []. That would be mathematically incorrect. [log()] is a whole different utility function that incorporates risk aversion.